# SQLITE3 2 level join with aggreation on middle level

Tags: sql, database, join, sqlite

we have 3 tables: grandfathers, fathers, sons. 
grandfathers have many fathers, and fathers have many sons, through the foreing keys grandfather_id and father_id.
Each record has only one property, the name of the person.

What I want is to have a list of all grandfathers, each with a field called grandsons_names which is the csv of all grandsons names. Fathers' names don't appear anywhere.

Here's my attempt to solve the problem:

```
SELECT grandfathers.*, group_concat(sons.name) 
FROM grandfathers 
    LEFT JOIN fathers ON grandfathers.id == fathers.grandfather_id 
    LEFT JOIN sons ON fathers.id == sons.father_id;
```

problem is.. only one grandfather shows up because aggregation is happening in the wrong place.. how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: Aren't you missing a GROUP BY clause in that code sample?

Comment: Why have you (someone) voted down this question? It's well expressed I think, and pertinent. If you think this was too easy, that's your problem, I did NOT know the answer and it has been very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it like that?

```
SELECT grandfathers.*, group_concat(sons.name) 
FROM grandfathers
LEFT JOIN fathers ON grandfathers.id = fathers.grandfather_id 
LEFT JOIN sons ON fathers.id = sons.father_id
GROUP BY grandfathers.id;
```